# Why did the regression coefficient changed sign when I added a trend variable in the regression?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, correlation, multiple-regression

I am modelling a linear regression of two retail prices. Correlation shows a positive relationship. When I regressed it with each other, it showed a positive coefficient. However, when I added a trend variable to, it was significant but the regression coefficient becomes negative. How did this happen?[[image: This is without trend and the next is when I added a trend][1]]

[image: This is with trend]

Comment: That often happens when the explanatory and objective variables follow a similar trend. Due to the similar trend, they have a positive correlation. Including the trend means you control the influence of the trend. The coefficient sign may change as a result.

Comment: @KotaMori then is the regression with trend still valid? How will I interpret this? Do you know any existing literature I can read about this?